# SQL AND without requirement

Tags: mysql

I have a table displaying on my website with a list of projects.  The SQL statement below pulls in each project and converts the ###_id columns to the ###_name in another table.  So far so good.

The problem I have is that this is requiring all fields in a row in the projects table to be filled out.  If, for example, the project row has no value for 'proj_industry_id' then the project won't display here at all.

I've tried removing the 'AND' for each match-up in the WHERE statement and separating them with commas, but it errors out.

I've also checked SQL docs and can't seem to find my way to an answer over there.

Any ideas on how I can get my statement to still match up the id with the name when I have one, but still show the record when I don't?

Thanks!

```
$sql = "SELECT
    projects.*,
    engagement_types.eng_type_name AS eng_type,
    users.user_full_name AS username,
    industries.industry_name AS industry_name,
    categories.category_name AS category_name,
    geographies.geo_name AS geo_name,
    status.status_name AS status_name
FROM
    projects,
    engagement_types,
    users,
    industries,
    categories,
    geographies,
    status
WHERE
    projects.proj_eng_type_id = engagement_types.id
    AND projects.proj_lead_id = users.id
    AND projects.proj_industry_id = industries.id
    AND projects.proj_category_id = categories.id
    AND projects.proj_geo_id = geographies.id
    AND projects.proj_status_id = status.id
    AND projects.proj_geo_id = '$selected_geo_id'";
```

*****EDIT******

Here is the final correct code from the solution below using multiple left joins!

```
SELECT
    projects.*,
    engagement_types.eng_type_name AS eng_type,
    users.user_full_name AS username,
    industries.industry_name AS industry_name,
    categories.category_name AS category_name,
    geographies.geo_name AS geo_name,
    status.status_name AS status_name
FROM 
    projects
LEFT JOIN engagement_types ON projects.proj_eng_type_id = engagement_types.id
LEFT JOIN users ON projects.proj_lead_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN industries ON projects.proj_industry_id = industries.id
LEFT JOIN categories ON projects.proj_category_id = categories.id
LEFT JOIN geographies ON projects.proj_geo_id = geographies.id
LEFT JOIN status ON projects.proj_status_id = status.id
GROUP BY
    proj_start_date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like your have to look at "LEFT JOIN" https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp
Otherwise you miss the left part of the green circle.

Comment: Nailed it.  THANK YOU!